# compile alsa + c + armv5tel in linux fedora 13 or 14 on VirtualBox

Tags: c, arm, alsa

I'm with a project, which I have to make a program that I take the volume of a microphone input on this and a few decibels parameters and we are interested to modify the entry so that the resulting output, speakers, is lower or higher depending on several things, such as environmental noise, micro-level audio, etc, etc.

I know what I mean more than one sounds like Chinese, I could check that the "pileup" as I call it so cool, you have an ARM architecture and is armv5tel subarchitecture, which is used under linux, but my great handicap = big problem, is to compile as typical compiling a C program to do so gcc file.c-o ficheroOut would already be solved.

But by working with linux audio libraries, which in this case I think are specific to linux armv5tel, not how to compile, for the typical linux audio program we put him in the-lasound and he would be but to be a different architecture Intel since no how.

Does anyone has worked with this architecture, language C and audio at once?, May I indicate how it can compile?

In principle, I found a solution that is compiled with arm-gp2x-linux-gcc or arm-none-linux-gcc, since I make a li file to any file that is already compiled, but not as they did, and as always I have no info as required that xDD that bastards and forgiveness, I give the following

file file

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, statically linked, not stripped

And for more info, to do a uname gives as arquitetura armv5tel, but with an unknown xDD linux, why?

Thanks if anyone can give me a clarification or light this bad feeling I have, because I have a couple of weeks I do not get very much, by Googling.

P. S.

It would have to use a QEMU (emulator for that particular architecture??), I am using a virtual machine with fedora 13 and within this an editor Kate, a former arm gcc and commented, but I can not compile properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have experience of audio stuff but I have been working with ARM-11 processor architecture and especially asm programming for this architecture. As a compiler I use [armcc](http://www.keil.com/arm/realview.asp#compiler) and for emulating/debugging on linux I am using [ARM RealView Debugger](http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/rvds/index.php) though gcc also supports [ARM assembly](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) and you can use QEMU as a emulator.

As a example this is line I am using for compiling files for ARM-11 in linux environment with armcc:

```
armcc -g -W --cpu=ARM1176JZ-S --arm {files}
```

In your case the --cpu= would be ARM5TEJ if I am right. Hope this helped you.